# onCreate not getting called for first activity when calling startActivity consecutively for two different activities

Tags: android

I have three activities **A**, **B**, and **C**.

In `onCreate()` of A, I call `startActivity(...)` in two consecutive statements for launching B & C. But android does not calls `onCreate()` on activity B instantly.
Instead when I press back on C since it is on top of stack. it calls `onCreate()` on B and the other lifecycle methods then.

Here is what my example code looks like.

```
public class A extends Activity {

  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  startActivity(this, B.class); 
  startActivity(this, C.class);
  }
}
```

Any clues to why the call to onCreate of activity B is getting deferred ?

Comment: Why are you doing such a thing?

Comment: I need to put a dummy activity in the middle of stack which I can then use to clear the stack through FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Answer (score 2):

In over simplified terms, you are pushing your startActivity command into a queue and B is waiting its turn.  If you want A -> B -> C, call C from B's onCreate.

Comment: I agree this seems the simplest solution, unless you want to wait in A until b is created then call startActivity on C, that doesn't sound wise.

Comment: I eventually need to finish() B when I press back from C. So I rectified it by calling finish() in B's onCreate (). But it looks weird to call finish() in onCreate when someone looks at my code :)

Answer (score 2):

It will en-queue your consecutive calls to onCreate. Once you press back on the last activity that is created (C, in this case) , activity B will be created causing onCreate to be called on B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish()` in `OnPause(`) of your Activity to clear the Activity from the Stack, instead of what you are doing.

Comment: onPause() is never called on B since it was not created. Only when I press back from C, it is created. So that does not solves the purpose. I guess other than how the code looks, I've implemented it rightly :)